〜た vs 〜ている when recalling the past
From 新完全マスターN1（文法）:

父の仕事の関係で、転勤と転校の繰り返しで大きくなった。
小学校だけで宇都宮、東京、鹿児島、四国の高松と4回（　）。 場数を踏んでいるとはいえ、新しい学校へお見えにゆく朝は、子供心に気が重かった。

The multiple choice options to fill in the blank were:


変化した
変化している
変えている
変わっている


The bolded choice, 変わっている is what the book says is the correct option.

Why not 変化した since the speaker is talking about the past? I know 〜ている can be used for narration about the past, but why is 〜た incorrect here?
If 〜ている is correct, why not 変化している?


This is not a matter of tense (た vs ている), but rather a matter of verb choice (変化する vs 変わる). Although 変わった is not in the options, it is also perfectly correct in this context.
変化する is used to refer to changes in the state or appearance of something itself, and it typically refers to a transitional or gradual change. In other words, it's not usually used for instant, "switching" or "choosing a new one" type changes such as:

❓ 会社の名前が変化する
❓ 担当者が変化する
❓ 住所が変化する
❓ 信号が変化する
❓ パスワードが変化する


Well, except for their versatility, is there a difference between た and ている?

@StarPeep There is little different at least in this context. "I moved" and "I've moved" are also often interchangeable in English.
